# facebook app and multiple site url

Tags: facebook

I have an facebook app
My user connect to my application with different url
    client_1.example.com
    client_2.example.com
    client_3.example.com

How I can precise in my facebook app that all the url with *.example.com can use my facebook app.

In the facebook app, I can precise the "site url" with http://www.example.com

How I can say, for example, http://*.example.com

Thanks for your help

Sylo